# Ubuntu Server installation and usage in VirtualBox much slower with multiple cores

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I wanted a fast 64-bit Ubuntu Server 14.0.4 LTS installation in a VirtualBox 5.0.0 VM on my OS X 10.10.4 host for testing. I left everything default but upped the # of cores to 4, half the cores of my host machine (2008 Mac Pro w/ 2 x 4-core Xeon CPUs) and gave it 2GB of RAM. The installation ISO and the virtual disk were on the same HDD. VT-x/AMD-V and Nested Paging were enabled, and PAE/NX was disabled, by default.

I noticed that every part of the installation was very slow, from choosing the language to writing files. After installation, the OS was running slowly. I stopped it, created a new VM and new virtual disk, and cranked it up to all 8 cores. It was ridiculously slow. It eventually seemed to get stuck forever on installing man-db, so I shut it down. I put it on just 1 core. The first parts of the installation (before writing files) were at least 100X as fast, and writing files was much faster too but not by 100X.

FreeBSD, on the other hand, worked fine whether I gave it 1 or 8 cores in VirtualBox. Very fast.

Is this a known issue? Is there a known fix? The issue is so severe that I suspect that having more cores is actually causing I/O errors, but that's just my guess.

Comment: Anything else running on the Mac? A common problem with VM software is that when you configure them to give n cores to a VM, they will only run when n cores on the host are simultaneously available.

Comment: How do you have the Ubuntu VM CPU settings configured (particularly the settings on the *Processor* and *Acceleration* tabs)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, other things are running on my Mac. How available do my cores need to be?

Comment: @mjturner I'll update the question. PAE/NX is disabled, VT-X/AMD-V and Nested Paging are enabled.

Comment: Someone told me that the Mac VirtualBox has issues with VT-x and Ubuntu. I'll try disabling VT-x once I'm ready to reboot my VM.

Comment: I've run into problems when I allocate cores in multiple VMs where the total equals or exceeds the number of actual cores on the host. Same issue with physical memory. Things started to thrash. Window manager was slow to respond, and it took 15 minutes for one VM to run a shutdown that ordinarily took 20 seconds.

Comment: D'oh, I can't even use multiple virtual CPUs without VT-x enabled. Looks like I'll stick with 1 or  2 then.